# getQueryParameterNames() only returning a single parameter

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am passing some data from a web application to a printer via intent, however, everytime i run getQueryParameterNames, it always returns only a single value.

The java code is

```
   protected void dispatch(Intent intent) {
    try {
        Uri link = intent.getData();

        if (link != null && link.getScheme().equals("parkit") && link.getHost().equals("print")) {
            Intent backgroundIntent = new Intent(this, Background.class);
            Uri uri= Uri.parse(intent.getDataString());


            /**
             * Extract the properties from the inbound intent and send them over as meta to the background service
             */
            Set<String> parameters = uri.getQueryParameterNames();

            //Start filling the treemap with the data if catagories is not empty
            if (!parameters.isEmpty()) {
                for (String parameter : parameters) {
                    backgroundIntent.putExtra(parameter, intent.getData().getQueryParameter(parameter));
                }
            }

            startService(backgroundIntent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

and the intent i am running is as follows:

> ./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d
>   "test://print?barcode=ABCDEFG&Reference=fasf"

I should see a size of 2 for parameters, but i only see the value 1 for size.

Any ideas

Comment: Can you please post the code from where you are sending this intent?

Comment: @PranaySoni updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following snippet of if condition

```
if (!parameters.isEmpty()) {
            for (String parameter : parameters) {
              backgroundIntent.putExtra(parameter, intent.getData().getQueryParameter(parameter));
            }
        }
```

in `backgroundIntent.putExtra(parameter, intent.getData().getQueryParameter(parameter));` the value of `parameter` key is over written every time and hence you are only getting the last over written value.